# Replay messages to Kafka topic on exception

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Our implementation is exactly same as implementation in this link :- [Acknowledge within @KafkaListener-method without "losing" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461268/acknowledge-within-kafkalistener-method-without-losing-messages)

```
`@KafkaListener(topics = "someTopic")
  public void listen(final String message, final Acknowledgment ack) {
    try {
        processMessage(message);
        ack.acknowledge();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // do not acknowledge here since we can temporarily not process the message
    }'
```

Our expectation was on IOException kafka will replay the messages on the topic till acknowledged manually. But this is not working as expected , the messages are not getting replayed on the kafka topic , is there work around for the same.

On exception thrown we want the message to be played automatically on the topic.

Comment: Technically what you are asking is done by the `DefaultErrorHandler`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling. Consider to just let that exception to be thrown from your listener method.

Comment: can can u show the kafka consumer configs ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good design practice to replay the message back to the source topic in the event of failure. You always need to design your KAFKA Client (Consumer), in such a way that, you should isolate your error handling and publish your event into a retry topic for the late processing. Also, it helps you maintain the order of processing events.

Kindly refer this https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/15/kafka-consumer-error-handling-retry-and-recovery/ for your better understanding.